# Strange errors when running npm install on alpine linux

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, alpine-linux

Dockerfile:

```
FROM iron/node
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

docker build log:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 198.2 MB
Step 1 : FROM iron/node
 ---> 9ca501065d18
Step 2 : RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a03d023f33e
Step 3 : RUN apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3e0176dae102
Step 4 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f9d925bd76c
Step 5 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> 0c2c195505dd
Removing intermediate container de7cb9edede2
Step 6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in d7549ec2707d
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_os_free_passwd: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_os_get_passwd: symbol not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What's going on? What these error mean?:

```
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_os_free_passwd: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_os_get_passwd: symbol not found
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on with that.  I obviously don't have your app, but I tried doing an npm install of a public module (e.g. [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman)) and I hit the same error. Looking at the [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/iron/node/) for that image, I found the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/iron-io/dockers/blob/master/node/Dockerfile) - which seems to uninstall npm. Indeed, when I ran that dockerfile directly, there was no npm - so I'm not sure how the public image still has it unless somehow their build process is a bit broken at the moment.

As a side note, it's a little inefficient to do this:

```
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Instead, you should install bash and curl at the same time:

```
RUN apk add --update bash curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Combining all those steps (i.e. using the dockerfile directly, and combining apk installs), and not uninstalling npm gives me:

```
FROM iron/base:edge

RUN echo '@edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
# RUN echo '@community http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
  && apk add nodejs@edge bash curl \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install -g newman
```

Which seemed to work fine.